# Vue Composition API - Can't add a property to an object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I'm using Vue's Composition API. When I write some code that adds a property to a `ref` object, the template renderer does not seem to detect the change. Here is my code:

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <button @click="updateObj">Click</button>
    <div v-if="obj[1]">{{ obj[1] }}</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent, ref } from "@vue/composition-api";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "App",
  setup() {
    const obj = ref({});

    const updateObj = () => {
      obj.value[1] = "hello";
      console.log(obj.value);
    };

    return {
      obj,
      updateObj,
    };
  },
});
</script>
```

Clicking on the button calls `updateObj` which then sets the property "1" on `obj` to "hello". If `obj[1]` is set, you should see "hello" in the browser, but nothing is displayed. [Here's a codepen to the demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/property-addition-jgb07?file=/src/App.vue).

I've been using the Composition API for months now and feel like I've gotten the hang of it, but  I have no idea what's going on here. I've also tried `reactive` instead of `ref` but still no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `ref` when you work with primitive values, if you want to use an object you have to use `reactive`, in [the official docs](https://composition-api.vuejs.org/#ref-vs-reactive) they say :

> If using ref, we are largely translating style (1) to a more verbose equivalent using refs (in order to make the primitive values reactive).
>
> - Using reactive is nearly identical to style (2). We only need to create the object with reactive and that's it.
> - Using reactive is nearly identical to style (2). We only need to create the object with reactive and that's it.

> ...
> Use ref and reactive just like how you'd declare primitive type variables and object variables in normal JavaScript. It is recommended to use a type system with IDE support when using this style.

To make it reactive assign the object directly to the ref's value :

```
 obj.value = { 1: "hello" };
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/property-addition-forked-4cnf7?file=/src/App.vue)**

Comment: The docs also say: "If an object is assigned as a ref's value, the object is made deeply reactive by the reactive method."  So ref still works for it.

Comment: Yes they mean something like `obj.value = { 1: "hello" };` not `obj.value[1] = "hello";` here a [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/property-addition-forked-4cnf7?file=/src/App.vue:331-358) compare it to the demo provided by in the OP

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim Your comment makes sense. It seems like directly assigning the `obj.value` is the way to go.

Comment: As i did in the demo

Answer (score 2):

*I'm adding my answer here so when I google this again in six months I'll find it.*

If you are using composition api with Vue 2, you need to use **set** to add a new tracked property to an object.

From https://github.com/vuejs/composition-api

> ⚠️ set and del workaround for adding and deleting reactive properties
> ⚠️ Warning: set and del do NOT exist in Vue 3. We provide them as a workaround here, due to the limitation of Vue 2.x reactivity system.
>
> In Vue 2, you will need to call set to track new keys on an
> object(similar to Vue.set but for reactive objects created by the
> Composition API). In Vue 3, you can just assign them like normal
> objects.
>
> Similarly, in Vue 2 you will need to call del to ensure a key deletion
> triggers view updates in reactive objects (similar to Vue.delete but
> for reactive objects created by the Composition API). In Vue 3 you can
> just delete them by calling delete foo.bar.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <button @click="updateObj">Click</button>
    <div v-if="obj[1]">{{ obj[1] }}</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent, ref, set } from "@vue/composition-api";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "App",
  setup() {
    const obj = ref({});

    const updateObj = () => {
      set(obj.value, 1, "hello");
      console.log(obj.value);
    };

    return {
      obj,
      updateObj,
    };
  },
});
</script>
```

[LIVE DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/property-addition-forked-mg8nw)